# angular2 how can I select only the .clicked DOM Element

Tags: angular

I am new in an angular world.
Shortly I have a list of items, I want when I click on the certain item in the list
the class of this clicked item only changed to another not all children of the same class

```
<tr (click)='selectItem()' [className]="isClicked ? 'active-class' : ''" *ngFor="let detial of receiptDetails">
    <td>{{detial.name}}</td>
    <td>{{detial.qty}}</td>
    <td> {{detial.Price}} </td>
    <td> {{detial.Price * detial.qty}} </td>
    <td> <button class='square_btn_x x-btn' (click)="removeDetail(detial)">X</button></td>
</tr>
```

the item that I want to click is in the tr tag 
`selectitem()` function is the function that I want to change the class to `active-class`

that is my type script code in the component

```
myStyle = {
    'display':'none'
}

isClicked=false;

selectItem(){
    this.isClicked=!this.isClicked;

    if (this.myStyle.display==='none') {
        this.myStyle.display='block';
    } else if (this.myStyle.display==='block') {
        this.myStyle.display='none';
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, i don't understand what exactly you want to achieve. But it seems that you espect a specific click on the row which is `tr`.
You should add the `(click)` event to your desired `td`.

Am I right?

Comment: No @AlbertoAM, he wants to apply a class to the clicked line, but right now it is applied to every line.

Comment: that i want to do  trichetriche

Answer (score 2):

Since there is an array of details and you want to select one or many, you cannot handle that with a single flag. You would need an `isClicked` flag for each detail. One possible solution is as follows.

and `className` is in `react`, not `angular`. You could use `ngClass` or the following approach.

Also, don't add typos to the names purposefully.

```
 <tr *ngFor="let detail of receiptDetails" (click)="selectItem(detail)" [class.active-class]="detail.isClicked" >
                        <td >{{detail.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{detail.qty}}</td>
                        <td> {{detail.Price}} </td>
                        <td> {{detail.Price * detial.qty}} </td>
                        <td> <button class='square_btn_x x-btn' (click)="removeDetail(detail)" >X</button></td>
                    </tr>
```

in ts,

```
selectItem(detail){
   detail.isClicked = !detail.isClicked;
   //... other logic
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but that is dont worked for me,
first the tr content is being hidden
second only i can select item and i cant toggle between other items

Comment: give me your exact problem so that I can help. This should work theoretically.

Comment: only the first item in list that can be selected now and the other not
i made my typescript
isClicked=false;

selectItem(detail){
  detail.isClicked = !detail.isClicked;
  //... other logic
}

Comment: we are not using the isClicked variable anymore. So that shouldn't matter. Copy your code to stackblitz and create a reproducable error.

Comment: thats work but only on the first tr(item)  in the table not all

Comment: The above code should work, and I honestly cannot debug unless you give me your code in a working environment :)